# How to open a rails href link from a Vue JS Method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vue.js, vuejs3

I'm working on a Rails/Vuejs project. I have a button with a href link inside that opens a Stripe modal. Since I also have a click event on that same button that close the main modal.
Problem: :/
The href click and the click event doesn't work properly and sometime the payement modal doesn't open because the click event take over the href link.

I'm trying to combine all the actions inside a method and do it asynchronously.

Here is what i have.

```
<b-button @click="handleSubmit"><a href="/card/new" data-remote='true'>Payment</a></b-button>
```

In my script tag, here is the rest on the actions.

```
handleSubmit() {
axios.post('/accommodations.json', {accommodation: this.accommodation})
    .then(response =>{
    if (response.status == 200) {
        this.$bvModal.hide('bv-modal-new_order');
        this.$emit('handleCreate');
   })
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `b-button` and `a` anchor elements appear to be competing for the click.

If you've determined that the user needs javascript to use the page, I'd say just get rid of the anchor element.

You can also try using modifiers, and even css to prevent click action from going to the child elements if you absolutely need to have the anchor there.

ie:

```html
<b-button @click.stop.capture="handleSubmit"><a href="/card/new" data-remote='true'>Payment</a></b-button>
```